# Django: only submit a form if what they entered in one field matches something in a different class

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am working on the registration for my website, and I need a way of verifying that a teacher belongs to the school that he/she says they do when applying, as the school class has a many to many field that all the teachers of the said school are in.

They way I have decided to do this, is to create a unique code for every school, and during the teachers registration, they need to enter the name of the school, and its code. If the code and the schools name match, they get registered, and if they dont, it throws an error.

These are the relevant classes:

```
class TeacherProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null = True, related_name = 'TeacherProfile', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    school = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    identification_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10, default = '')    
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    head_of_subject = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    headmaster = models.BooleanField(default = False)


    def username(self):
        return self.user.username

    def fullname(self):
        return (self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name)

class SchoolProfile(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '', unique = True)
    identification_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10, unique = True)
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(TeacherProfile, blank = True)
```

The form I use for this:

```
class TeacherRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)
    school = forms.CharField(required = True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required = True)
    head_of_subject = forms.BooleanField(required = True)
    identification_code = forms.CharField(required = True)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TeacherRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].help_text = ''
    self.fields['password2'].help_text = ''


class Meta:
    model = User

    fields = (
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'school',
        'identification_code',
        'subject',
        'head_of_subject',
        'password1',
        'password2'            
    )

def save(self, request):
    form = TeacherRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    user = User.objects.create(first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                        last_name=self.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                        email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
                        username=self.cleaned_data['username'])

    teacher_profile = TeacherProfile.objects.create(user=user,
                                                    school=self.cleaned_data['school'],
                                                    subject=self.cleaned_data['subject'],
                                                    identification_code=self.cleaned_data['identification_code'],
                                                    head_of_subject=self.cleaned_data['head_of_subject'],
                                                    )


    return user, teacher_profile
```

I think I need to do something in my view for this to preform this verification, however, I am not sure how to do so. This is the relevant part of my view:

```
elif search_req == 'teacher':

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = TeacherRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            user, teacher_profile = form.save(request)

            return render(request, 'accounts/home.html')
        else:
            args = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)

    else:
        form = TeacherRegistrationForm()
        args = {'form': form}                
        return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Put a if condition in your view for checking this using a db query (ORM) .

Comment: Ive written a method in the model
`def school_name_and_code(self):
     return [self.school_name, self.identification_code]`

And have tried calling it in the view with `school_info  =request.school_name_and_code()`

But i get an error saying 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'school_name_and_code'

I dont know how i can tell it to return the data of a specific school that the user has entered in school_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a matter of how you relate the Teacher and School models. If a Teacher can related to multiple Schools, Then there will be ManyToMany relationship between them.

In the form it is not ideal to let the user type the School name, since there can be mistakes when entering it. Best way is to provide a drop-down list to select the School. Then you don't have to ask the user the fill in the unique code of the School.

You need to validate the Teacher if he/she belongs to the School mentioned when applying. Then you have to first get the relevant School object and find if the given Teacher (by name) is a valid foreign key of Teacher.

You can do the validation of the form two ways.

1. Validate at form submission: Here full form is submitted and validated for your condition. If this fails return the form again with the error messages.
2. Ajax call: When the user has finished entering the School name and his/her name (Not a good idea anyway since there can be mistakes when typing) validate the Teacher with an Ajax call with the server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Eventually I am planning on having a drop down list, however I currently just want to get the registration to work. I have no experience with an AJAX what so ever. As suggested above, before the form is saved, I should get the code of the school that user entered and compare that against the code they entered, however I am unsure as to how to query it

Comment: Set the value property with unique id of the School for each School option in your drop-down. Then this will be submitted with the form so that you can use it to query the School object. You can simply use the full form validation instead of Ajax call.

Comment: You can query for School object this way. Suppose the value send by the user is `unique_school_id`. Then according to you model you can check `school_object = SchoolProfile.objects.get(identification_code=unique_school_id)`. If the object is valid (i.e. not `None`) code is correct.

Comment: Small correction: `get` method throws an exception if the object is not found. Therefore enclose the get method call in a `try-except` block instead of checking if the `school_object` is `None`.